# How to make mouse moves in Excel independent of screen resolution?

Tags: excel, vba, mouse

I would like to create an Excel elearning tutorial (blended learning) for some coworkers.
I would like to use vba/vbs to move the mouse over the screen and show them where the different commands are located.
I know that this can be done, but when you change the screen resolution it no longer works.
Is there any way to make it independent of the screen resolution?

I.e.:
Move mouse slowly to "Bold"-Button and click on it, regardless of what tab is currently selected and the screen resolution?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Seems like it would save you a lot of time to just record yourself with a screen recorder rather than make a complicated VBA routine.

Comment: Excel is not meant for this. But then Yes it is possible to achieve what you want. However it is very complicated and not very practical. I second the suggestion given by @PortlandRunner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This would be best achieved with a screen video capture tool
2. If you insist, create a pointer-shaped shape on the worksheet and use some version of the attached code to move it around

   ```
   Sub MoveShape(shp As Shape, dbTop As Double, dbLeft As Double)
   Dim dbVerticalIncrement As Double, dbHorizontalIncrement As Double
   Dim lLoop As Long
   Const lSteps As Long = 1000


   dbVerticalIncrement = (dbTop - shp.Top) / lSteps
   dbHorizontalIncrement = (dbLeft - shp.Left) / lSteps

   For lLoop = 1 To lSteps
       shp.Top = shp.Top + dbVerticalIncrement
       shp.Left = shp.Left + dbHorizontalIncrement
       Application.Wait (Now() + 0.0000001)
   Next lLoop

   End Sub
   ```